# Prevent page from reload on submission but keep saving in the database

Tags: html, ajax, database, laravel

I want to submit the form when I select an option from select option but I don't want the page to reload after doing that. 
I used the `e.preventDefaut()` but the form stops saving to the database.
PS: it was saving perfectly before adding the `preventDefault` but the page does reload.

Here is my code for the form:-

```
<form action="{{route('course.add')}}" method="POST"  > 
    @csrf

    <div class="aa">
        <div class="dd">

                <input type='checkbox' id='HiddenCheck{{$course->id}}' >
                <input class='red' id = "b{{$course->id}}"  onclick="showComboBox({{$course->id}})" >

                <label class="class_name" value ="{{$course->id}}" >{{$course->courseNumber}}</label>
                <input hidden type="number" value="{{$course->id}}"  name ="course"/>
        </div>

        <div class="select-style" id="check{{$course->id}}" hidden >
            <select name="a" id="season" >
            <option value="" selected disabled hidden>Taken on </option>
            <option value="Summer">Summer</option>
            <option value="Fall">Fall</option>
            <option value="Winter">Winter</option>
            <option value="Spring">Spring</option>
            </select>
        </div>
    </div>
</from>
```

and here is my Ajax code to submit the form:-

```
$('#season').on('change', function(e) {
    e.preventDefault() ;
    $(this).closest('form').submit();

});
```

I was expecting the form to be submitted and my data added to the database without reloading the page.
But when I added the `preventDefaut()` the data stop saving in the database.

Comment: Use Ajax: https://stackoverflow.com/a/5004276/8352986

Answer (score 1):

You can submit the form with ajax.

**First solution - With onChange submit**

Assuming you have a submit button with id `btn-submit`.

Add a `id` to the form, like `my-form`.

```js
$(".select-style").on('change', function(){
    $.ajax({
        url: 'your-route-here',
        method: 'post',
        data: {
            $("#my-form").serialize(),
        },
        success: function(response){
            alert('ok');
        }
    });
});
```

**Second one - With button submit**

You can use the [ajaxForm/ajaxSubmit](https://jquery-form.github.io/form/) functions from Ajax Form Plugin or the jQuery serialize function.

- With ajax form:

```js
$("#theFormId").ajaxForm({url: 'server.php', type: 'post'});
```

or

```js
$("#theFormId").ajaxSubmit({url: 'server.php', type: 'post'});
```

ajaxForm will send when the submit button is pressed. ajaxSubmit sends immediately.

Hope it helps.

Comment: the thing that I need to submit the form after choosing an option from the select option that why I used the  select onchange to submit the form

Comment: I changed the on click to on change. The first solution should work

Comment: in the URL should I just put 'course.add'? 
if so, it doesn't work for me

Answer (score 1):

Try using ajax post request

```
$('#season').on('change', function(e){
 e.preventDefault() ;
     var url = e.target.action  // get the target
     var formData = $(this).serialize() // get form data
     $.post(url, formData, function (response) { // send; response.data will be what is returned
         alert('data sent')
     })
 });
```

Comment: I tried it but it doesn't work, even if I remove the preventDefault still not working